# How to set up a device to prevent un-activated users from logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I added an attribute called activated to my user. If it is 0, I want to prevent login, if it is 1, I want to allow it. I overrode the device sessions controller to be like this

```
def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")

  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  if resource.activated == 0
    redirect_to root_path
    return
  end
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

and my routes are like this

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :sessions => 'sessions'} do
   get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

why does it still allow login for users with activated = 0. (Im assuming this is the function called at login.)

Comment: You should use a boolean value for the `activated` field, it would be much more intuitive.

Comment: @DevinM true, but it's already int (and i think ive assigned a field as a bool in an app before, and got an error because bool wasn't a type ... i think ... how do u name the type as bool)

Comment: You want to use the type `boolean` not `bool` see this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `confirmable` it would allow you to have the same functionality without writing custom code. The [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable) explains it well enough and it should make sense.

> Confirmable is responsible to verify if an account is already
>   confirmed to sign in, and to send emails with confirmation
>   instructions. Confirmation instructions are sent to the user email
>   after creating a record and when manually requested by a new
>   confirmation instruction request.

If you don't want to send the email then there are ways to disable it and you can write your own method to confirm and enable the accounts.

Comment: i wrote a custom thing to send email and activate the user. I guess i could look at this, thanks. (If u can see the problem in my code let me know, so i dont feel like i wasted alot of time)

Comment: Just use the code that they provide, no sense in making something new when you don't have to. Also look into using version control fro your project. I recommend mercurial or git, you can roll back changes this way and save time.

Comment: Just commit locally, you can always clean up later with `git rebase` and its better that you keep a trail of changes.